# "Software diversification effect" or "software diversification effectiveness"?

Tags: grammar, writing, academia

here is my quick question, when I want to say "software diversity" (this is considered as a technical term), which one is the most suitable way? given the context below:

```
XXXXX, with an amplified diversification effectiveness bends well with the XXXXX.
```

1. diversification effectiveness
2. diversification effect
3. diversity effectiveness
4. diversity effect
5. diversifying effectiveness
6. diversifying effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which to choose from your question, but I hope the following will be useful...

Diversification effectiveness - this means that diversity gives effectiveness

Diversification effect - this means that there is a specific effect (that may be good or bad) that comes from diversification

Diversity - this is most frequently used at the moment to do with issues of race, gender, sexuality etc. e.g. in diversity issues when selecting speakers for a conference or engaging a new employee. - .... on its own **diversity effectiveness** suggests that a racially/gender balanced team will be more effective....

Diversifying... this suggests that the software is in the process of being diversified, which is not what you want here ( I am guessing ).

So I would suggest something like

XXXX, with the effectiveness of a diverse software set bends well with the XXX

hope this is useful